# Why would git merge set my svn url to the branch

Tags: git-svn

On my master checkout I can do a `git svn info` and the url is `svn://myrepo.com/trun`k
when on my new_feature checkout the svn url is `svn://myrepo.com/branches/new_feature`.

After running a `git merge new_feature` on my master checkout the master url is changed to `svn://myrepo.com/branches/new_feature`. This makes both my master and new_feature pointing to the some place and I can no longer `git svn dcommit` to trunk.

NOTE: This was working last week, and the only thing I can think of that could be different is that I needed to update the branch to trunk. I ran `git merge trunk` on my branch. Perhaps it git will no longer let me merge my branch back to trunk now?

I would like to know why this is and how to keep that from happening or fix it after it has happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

git svn doesn't make a serious attempt at representing git merges in the svn data model (possibly because it can't be done properly). The svn branch information is picked up from git log messages; somehow the new_feature appeared first in the log. Following the first merge parent would have been better (edit: git-svn probably did, see below).

Anyway, the recommended way to handle this is not to record merges (using `git merge --squash` instead), or to switch to git completely.

Seeing your edit: your merge back into trunk must have been a fast-forward. So git-svn followed the first parent of the first merge it saw, which was the merge of trunk into new_feature, until it found a log message with git-svn metadata. Prevent git from fast-forwarding merges into trunk by using `git merge --no-ff feature_branch`.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to fix it. by creating a new local/trunk branch and running the git merge --squash. It would appear that the first merge from trunk to new_feature without --squash did the real damage. Thank you, for your help. Corporate politics aside I would love to move to git fully.

Answer (score 0):

per the [git documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn):

```
If you do merge, note the following rule: git svn dcommit will

attempt to commit on top of the SVN commit named in

git log --grep=^git-svn-id: --first-parent -1
```

...so when you merged your `new-feature` branch (which had been dcommitted and has a git log with a `git-svn-id` pointing to its branch) into your `master` branch (which prior to the merge had a `git-svn-id` log pointing to trunk) you gave `master` a `--first-parent` log with `git-svn-id` pointing to the wrong branch `new-feature`

This is why there warnings all over the place to be careful when merging stuff backed by svn (or not to do it at all).